# How to get selected clash result items from Clash Detective UI using Navisworks API

Tags: autodesk-navisworks

I am using Navisworks 2022 version.
I have tried Navisworks API and also ComAPI to get the selected clash result items from Clash Detective UI. But couldn't find any API related to that.

Could you please help with it?

Answer (score 1):

For now, there is no such function to get the selected clash results or groups from Navis API. Instead, you can bind the list of clash results to a custom view you create it and then get the selections from your own view.